# My MainActivity lags while using android older versions (oreo for example) but works smoothly in the latest version , how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-api-levels

My MainActivity lags/not scrolling smoothly while using android older versions (oreo for example) but works smoothly in the latest version , I'm facing this trouble only in the main page only , the main layout is Coordinator layout.

**this is the main :**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 // Menu options :
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
     return true;
 }
```

dataBase db =new dataBase(this);

```
 Toolbar toolbar;
 CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
 boolean ischecked =false;

 LottieAnimationView lotti ;
 AppCompatImageView logo ;
 Animation animation ;
```

// the main options :

```
 AppCompatImageView imageView1 ;
 AppCompatImageView imageView2 ;
 AppCompatImageView imageView3 ;
 AppCompatImageView imageView4 ;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 //Tablet Screen Configuration : 

    int seze = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
    if ((seze & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)== Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ) {

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    
  //end of configuration

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
   imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
   imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
```

// DataBase Stuff :

```
    SharedPreferences shrd2 = getSharedPreferences("forbidden",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int e=shrd2.getInt("d",0);


    if (e==0) {
        db.createDataBase();
        SharedPreferences shrd= getSharedPreferences("forbidden",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shrd.edit();
        editor.putInt("d",1);
        editor.apply();
    }
 // end of DataBase Stuff



// Images and main layout Yoyo animation Effect :

    YoYo.with(Techniques.Bounce).duration(1100).delay(500).playOn(imageView1) ;
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Bounce).duration(1100).delay(1100).playOn(imageView2) ;
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Bounce).duration(1100).delay(2100).playOn(imageView3) ;
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Bounce).duration(1100).delay(3100).playOn(imageView4) 


 // Logo amimation :

    logo = findViewById(R.id.logo) ;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.floating);
    logo.startAnimation(animation) ;



 // CoordiantorLayout animated background  :

    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.CoordinatorLayout);
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) coordinatorLayout.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2500);
    animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5000);
    animationDrawable.start();


 // Toolbar Menu :

    toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.MaToolBar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.mainmenu);
```

// Floating button explosion transition :

```
     final boolean[]r=new boolean[1] ;
     r[0]=false;
     
     final FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    
    final int[] x =new int[1];
    final int[] y=new int[1];
    button.post(() -> {
        // Values should no longer be 0
        int[] point = new int[2];
        button.getLocationInWindow(point); // or getLocationInWindow(point)
         x[0] = point[0];
         y[0] = point[1];
        r[0]=true;
        

    final int[] xx=new int[1];
    final int[] yy=new int[1];

        xx[0] = x[0];
        yy[0] = y[0];


        
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (r[0]==true) {
                    // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookMark_Activity.class));
                    Intent getPosition = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookMark_Activity.class);
                    getPosition.putExtra("x", xx[0]);
                    getPosition.putExtra("y", yy[0]);
                    getPosition.putExtra("ShouldRun",true);
                    startActivity(getPosition);
                }
            }

        });
});
// end of Floating button explosion transition 




  // Lottie Animation bottom :

    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView= findViewById(R.id.lottiebottom);
    lottieAnimationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ischecked){
                lottieAnimationView.setSpeed(-1);
                lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
                ischecked=false;
            }else {
                lottieAnimationView.setSpeed(1);
                lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
                ischecked=true;
            }
        }
    });




} // end of OnCreate method
```

//floating button animation stuff

```
 private int getDips(int dps) {
     Resources resources = getResources();
     return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
             TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
             dps,
             resources.getDisplayMetrics());
 }
```

//Images Options for intent :

```
public void options (View view){


        if(view.getTag().toString().equals("Is101")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,welcome.class) ;
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right , R.anim.slide_out_left);

        }else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("Ar")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,welcome_ar.class) ;
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right , R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("HRLC")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,welcome_hrlc.class) ;
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right , R.anim.slide_out_left);

        }else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("HIST")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,welcome_hist.class) ;
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right , R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }


}


 public void onBackPressed() {

     // Dialog box :

     ViewDialogMain alert2 = new ViewDialogMain();
     alert2.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Bahrain Exams");



 }
```

}   // end of the class

**and this is the XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/CoordinatorLayout"
layout_height="7dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_list">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bookmarkpngg"

    app:backgroundTint="#AFAEAE"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="234dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transpa_colorerd"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/app_color"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="Bahrain Exams"
        app:titleEnabled="true"

        >


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/lottiesecond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:rotation="-7.1"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:scaleX="1.3"
                android:scaleY="1.3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.796"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/flyingman" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="249dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/officiallogosecond"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/MaToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/transpa_scroll"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/alconstreain2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/is"
                android:foreground="@drawable/is"
                android:onClick="options"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/uob"
                android:tag="Is101" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:foreground="@drawable/Ar"
                android:onClick="options"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/eglish"
                android:tag="Ar" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:foreground="@drawable/hrlc"
                android:onClick="options"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/maths"
                android:tag="HRLC" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:foreground="@drawable/hist"
                android:onClick="options"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/hist"
                android:tag="HIST" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/lottiebottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/taskman" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely Compatibility issues.
Make sure all your Project structure take advantage of the Android Jetpack Architecture.

For Example:
use `AppCompatButton`  instead of  `Button`
use `LinearLayoutCompat`  instead of `LinearLayout` 
... and so on.

Comment: I tried , nothing happened unfortunately :(

Comment: if you can post your ``` MainActivity``` and the corresponding .XML  layout code, it'll be helpful

Comment: just posted them